# Linear algebra , vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

> A robot arm is moved along the directions , $$a_1 =(1,-1,2),a_2 = (3,0,-1),a_3 =(7,-1,0)$$ 
>   Can the robot arm reach any point in the space?

I tried to answer but I don't know whether it is correct.

Space is $\mathbb R^3$ then  took point in space as $(1,2,3)$ then $$(1,2,3) = r(1,-1,2)+p(3,0,-1)+s(7,-1,0)$$ when finding $r,p,s$ it gives contradiction $3=-1/3$ therefore it cannot reach some points on the space.

Is this correct? To which main directions it can be moved? Is it the mentioned directions in the question??

Comment: Knowing what linear independence means would imply that alternatively, you could have checked if the determinant of the matrix with the 3 vectors above was $0$.

Comment: The idea you're using is correct, although I'd argue the explanation is a bit vague. Essentially, you assume the answer is 'yes', and then go for contradiction by considering the point $(1,2,3)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $a_1 + 2a_2 = a_3$.

Hence the robot arms just effectively span along the direction of linear combination of $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Just stand in the direction of $a_1 \times a_2$ and the robot arm can't reach you.

Note that the point $(1,2,3)$ can't be reached as well.

Comment: Our syllabus doesnot contains cross product only dot product so how i find main direction ?

Comment: The robot arms only span along linear combiniation of $a_1$ and $a_2$. That is it can only move in a two dimensional plane.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know if $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are linearly dependent , i.e do there exists solutions to
$$c_1(1,-1,2)+c_2(3,0,-1)+c_3(7,-1,0)=0$$
other than $c_1=c_2=c_3=0.$
This is clearly the case since
$$(c_1,c_2,c_3)=(1,2,-1)$$
is a solution.